# Django send POST request to views.py with CSRF token, then redirect page

Tags: django, django-views, braintree, django-csrf, csrf-token

I originally had an AJAX call to my view, then I realized I can't `return render(request, 'my/new/template.html, context)`

So I came upon this related question, which led me to what I show below: [Redirect to new page after receiving data from Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38400221/redirect-to-new-page-after-receiving-data-from-javascript)

However I'm having trouble getting the CSRF token to work, it's giving me a 403 error. As a side note, I am also using shell_plus to use a secure connection, but I don't think that is contributing to the issue.

Here is my call to the view function:

```
submitForm.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {

    const form = new FormData(e.target);
    // const csrf_token = form.get("csrfmiddlewaretoken");
    // instead using var csrf_token = {{ csrf_token }} in template
    e.preventDefault()
    instance.requestPaymentMethod(function (err, payload) {
      var url = '/shop/payment/';
      var newForm = '<form action="' + url + '" method="post">';
      newForm += '<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="' + csrf_token +'" />'
      newForm += '<input type="hidden" name="paymentMethodNonce" value="' + payload.nonce + '" />'
      newForm += '<input type="hidden" name="orderTotal" value="' + order_total + '" />'
      newForm += '<input type="hidden" name="address" value="' + $('#address-select').val() + '" />
      newForm += '<input type="hidden" name="first-name" value="' + form.get("first-name") + '" />'
      newForm += '<input type="hidden" name="last-name" value="' + form.get("last-name") + '" />'
      newForm += '</form>'
      var form_element = $(newForm);
      $('body').append(form_element);
      form_element.submit();
    });
```

My previous attempt using ajax looked something like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/shop/payment/',
        headers: { "X-CSRFToken": csrf_token },
        data: {
            'paymentMethodNonce': payload.nonce,
            'orderTotal': order_total,
            'address': $('#address-select').val(),
            'first-name': form.get("first-name"),
            'last-name': form.get("last-name")
        }
}).done(function (result) {
     console.log(result.result)
    // WON'T REDIRECT
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using a regular form with method="post":

```
<form id="braintree-submit-form" method="post" action="{% url 'shop:payment' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
{# added any inputs I could get from the template here, for example #}
<input type="text" name="first-name" class="form-control" value="{{ request.user.first_name}}" required />
{# ... #}
```

I still needed to add some form inputs, whose values I could only access through javascript but I ended up with a much shorter simpler function. The reason is this is an implementation of [Braintree's Dropin UI](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/overview/javascript/v3).

```
submitForm.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault()

    instance.requestPaymentMethod(function (err, payload) {

        var nonceInput = document.createElement("input")
        nonceInput.setAttribute('name', 'paymentMethodNonce')
        nonceInput.setAttribute('value', payload.nonce)
        nonceInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden')
        submitForm.appendChild(nonceInput)

        var addrInput = document.createElement("input")
        addrInput.setAttribute('name', 'address')
        addrInput.setAttribute('value', $('#address-select').val())
        addrInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden')
        submitForm.appendChild(addrInput)

        submitForm.submit()
    })
```