# How to send a list of objects to the next Django template?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I have a list of objects in my Django template.Each object can be selected and added to a list. I need to send the list to the next template. How can i send the list to the next template?
Thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use this question which has a nice answer : [redirect to new page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38400221/redirect-to-new-page-after-receiving-data-from-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

if your list is in html you can add a input hidden for each element.
if your list is a json array you can send by post using ajax

Comment: I have sent it by post using ajax but the problem is that by using ajax the new template won't get loaded.how can i solve this?thanks @Cesar Abel Ramirez

Comment: you receive the request and put de data in the context and return the new rendered template